# Replace strings between two characters using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2014

I need to update a string to amend any aliases - which can be 'H1.', 'H2.', 'H3.'... etc - to all be 'S.' and am struggling to work out the logic.
For example I have this:

> 'H1.HUB_CUST_ID, H2.HUB_SALE_ID, H3.HUB_LOC_ID'

But I want this:

> 'S.HUB_CUST_ID, S.HUB_SALE_ID, S.HUB_LOC_ID'

If you could use wildcards in REPLACE, I'd do something like this REPLACE(@string, 'H%.H', 'S.H').

Theoretically, there is no limit to how many H# aliases there could be. In practice there will almost definitely be less than 10.

Is there a better way than a nested replace of H1 - H10 separately, which both looks messy in a script and carries a small risk if more tables are joined in future?

Comment: This is going to be hard to swing in SQL Server, which basically has no regex support.  I vote for normalizing your data first, then handling this requirement outside the database.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've edited it to simplify my problem, but in reality the string is a long SQL script, which is almost entirely as required apart from these aliases - so normalising doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @JShark in that case it's best to use any other tool except T-SQL. There shouldn't be any reason to perform such conversions in real time, you should be able to produce the correct script earlier. You could use Powershell to construct this and use regex for replacements, a small C# program or an editor's regex replace function

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support pattern replacement. You are better off using a different language, that does support pattern/REGEX replacement or implementing a CLR function.

That said, however, considering you said that the value would always be below 10 you *could* brute force it, but it's not "pretty".

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourString,'H1.','S.'),'H2.','S.'),'H3.','S.'),'H4.','S.'),'H5.','S.'),'H6.','S.'),'H7.','S.'),'H8.','S.'),'H9.','S.')
FROM YourTable ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to XML and then convert it into simple table:

```
DECLARE @txt nvarchar(max) = N'H1.HUB_CUST_ID, H2.HUB_SALE_ID, H3.HUB_LOC_ID',
        @x xml 

SELECT @x = '<a al="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@txt,', ','</a><a al="'),'.','">')+ '</a>'

SELECT t.c.value('@al', 'nvarchar(max)') as alias_name,
       t.c.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as col_name
FROM @x.nodes('/a') t(c)
```

Output:

```
alias_name   col_name
H1           HUB_CUST_ID
H2           HUB_SALE_ID
H3           HUB_LOC_ID
```

You can put results into temp table, amend them using `LIKE 'some basic pattern'` and then build new string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the result order, you can unaggregate and reaggregate:

```
select t.*, v.new_val
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(concat('S1', stuff(s.value, 1, charindex('.'), '') - 1, ',') within group (order by (select null) as newval
      from string_split(t.col, ',') s
     ) s;
```

Note:  This assumes that all values start with the prefix you want to replace -- as your sample data suggests.  A `case` expression can be used if there are exceptions.

You can actually get the original ordering -- assuming no duplicates -- using `charindex()`:

```
select t.*, v.new_val
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(concat('S1', stuff(s.value, 1, charindex('.'), '') - 1, ',')
                         within group (order by charindex(s.value, t.col)
                       ) as newval
      from string_split(t.col, ',') s
     ) s;
```